# Google oAuth2 AuthMissingParameter

Tags: django, google-oauth

I'm trying to use Google oAuth2 for login. I get this error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/?code=blah
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: AuthMissingParameter
Exception Value:    
Missing needed parameter state
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\social_core\backends\oauth.py
```

My settings.py has the secret set, I don't know what to set in the KEY. Is that the problem? I checked the clients_secrets.json file and I see nothing called KEY. Not sure where this KEY comes from

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET ="SECRET*"
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY=""
```

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials go to the link and register your project, select the oauth api and create and get key and secret

Comment: Thanks let me try it

Answer (score 2):

I would like to try to help you how to get the google OAuth2.0 parameter. I have read some documentation about python social auth in here [python social auth doc](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/google.html).

And of course, you have to fill client ID and client secret to enable Google OAuth2.0 (or to another google API). To get client ID and client secret you can obtain it from here [Acquiring client IDs and secrets](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth).

`SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'API KEY FROM GOOGLE'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'SECRET FROM GOOGLE'`

And if you follow the instruction, you will be in Google API to generate you client IDs and secret.

Answer (score 0):

You must go here and create an app for yourself https://console.developers.google.com/, then get the SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY, SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET from the credentials. 
if you any doubts go through this  http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html